# PHP add key while a foreach without using '&' (reference)

Tags: php, foreach

Suppose I am looping an array like this:

```
foreach($cursor as $obj) { ... }
```

and the values inside are as following:

```
$obj['name'] => "foo"
$obj['surname'] => "test"
```

is there a way to add another key and value inside it, directly from the foreach, without using '&'? Something like this:

```
foreach($cursor as $obj) { $obj['age'] = 24; }
```

but without using this:

```
foreach($cursor as &$obj) { $obj['age'] = 24; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foreach ($cursor as $key => $obj) {$cursor[$key]['age'] = 24;}`

Comment: Why don't you want to loop "by reference"? IS there a valid reason?

Comment: yes, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531554/php-var-dump-and-loop-giving-different-results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach($cursor as $k => $obj) { 
    $cursor[$k]['age'] = 24; //or whatever else you want to change it to
}
```

Comment: It adds an empty element into the array with age => 0, and the other elements do not gain age => 24.

Comment: @johnsmith Oops, I typed `cursor` instead of `obj`. Fixed it.

Comment: it still doesn't. The value for 'age' is not added into the array; but this time there no empty array :)

Comment: Using `$cursor[$k]` you get the value of `$obj`. `$obj[$k]` makes no sense.

Comment: @MihaiStancu You're right, it's late and I don't have my head screwed on straight. Thanks!

Comment: @johnsmith Mihai Stancu has fixed the problem with my answer